# Rewrite URL query string for all pages

Tags: url-rewriting, query, htaccess

I need to pass query string

http://example.com/anypage?query=123

to look like this:

http://example.com/anypage/123

and it should work on any page:

...com/anotherpage/123

I am looking for the simplest way to do this on wordpress. It would be awesome if it could be achieved on htaccess, because I am not really into wordpress functions and it's very hard for me to deal with it.

What I already tried are some functions from this question: [How can I Rewrite a 'page' URL based on query string parameters?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61971/how-can-i-rewrite-a-page-url-based-on-query-string-parameters)

One that I thought will be successful from the same question was this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(onepage)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&query=$matches[2]','top');

add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'query';
    return $vars;
}
```

I have added it to my theme functions and have tried checking that "/onepage" to get code firstly working only on it (because I am not sure how to make it work on all of the pages).

So however I wasn't able to get it working.

I can't find a way to the answer, but I believe, there is really simple solution for this. Maybe someone of you know it? Or maybe you could give some tip to find the solution?

Comment: The linked question already has a complete answer. What exactly has you tried without success? Please, post the code you have tried or we can end up repeating the same already said in the linked quesiton.

Comment: @cybmeta I have updated my question with one of the codes from that another question, that I tried. I added this code only because I think it should be successful as it is marked as right answer on another question. However it doesn't work for me.

Comment: what happens when you want to have a child page? how will you distinguish between a child page and your querystring value?