# Url Rewriting a dynamic wordpress page

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I am in a little trouble on wordpress, hope you can help me :)

I have a sub-page that i can call with different paramater :

- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=ADA
- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=ARDR

I want to make clean urls and dismiss the sub-page name :

- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/ADA.html
- https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/ARDR.html

To do this, i tried this add_rewrite_rule :

```
function add_directory_rewrite() {
add_rewrite_tag("%symbol%", '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^crypto-monnaies/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html', '/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/?symbol=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_directory_rewrite' );
```

The problem is that when i call the rewrited url, it redirect me to https://www.cryptolia.fr/crypto-monnaies/showcoin/ without the parameter

so first it should not be a 301 redirect, and second : it should carry the parameter so i can grab it in PHP.

thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Rewrite a 'page' URL based on query string parameters?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61971/how-can-i-rewrite-a-page-url-based-on-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Check out this similar question and answer on stack overflow which walks you through the custom function to write.  Be sure to also flush rewrite rules/ permalinks when you've finished updating your code:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076665/wordpress-pass-query-string-as-slash-based-url

Comment: for the 2nd argument of `add_rewrite_rule`, try with the direct URL of the custom post like `index.php?crypto-monnaies=ADA&symbol=$matches[1]`

Comment: You have a mixture of internal and external rule syntax. WordPress assumes any rule that doesn't point to `index.php` is external, and puts it in the htaccess file, but you are using `$matches[1]`, which is PHP and invalid in an htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for you reply,

So after much digging, it's working :

```
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
   add_rewrite_tag( '%symbol%', '([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)' );
   add_rewrite_rule( '^crypto-monnaies/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$', 'index.php?
pagename=showcoin&symbol=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule');

function add_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
   $query_vars[] = 'symbol';
   return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars' );
```

Please note that if you dynamic page is a second level page, you have to call the ?pagename=parent-page/child-page (with the slash).

To resolve my problem i put the "showcoin" page to first level.